# Camera Distorts Mesh

Tags: mesh, modifiers, armature, bones, camera

Seeking help on below.

I was trying to set up my camera to prepare for rendering but whenever I clicked on CTRL+ALT+0, it distorts my mesh.

I have tried to:

- Delete the camera and added a new one
- I have tried ALT+P to the camera to remove any parenting, just in case it was attached to the mesh.
- I tried to apply the scale, rotation and location.
- I tried to apply the Armature Modifier but the mesh and bones is not anymore connected

But still have no good results.

This is how it looks without the camera view:

[image]

Whenever I hit CTRL+ALT+O, the mesh is deformed:

[image]

From above image, if I go to edit mode it shows like this.

[image]

Now when I tried to apply the ARMATURE modifier and hit CTRL+ALT+0, the mesh is not deformed but is not with the bones anymore. Also, I'm not sure if ARMATURE modifiers should be applied or what is the practice for this?

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going back to this, I got a solution from someone.

What I have done was to open a new Blender scene and delete everything in the 3D viewport. Then file → append and find the old .blend and to objects and hit the A key and append all the objects. And it worked.

The character is no longer distorted whenever I try to position the camera.

Answer (score 0):

Important thing to know when using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> shortcut: **only a camera object** should be selected.

If another element is selected instead of a camera, it will be moved to the chosen viewpoint and rotated to match the orientation of a camera object.

I think that's the issue here. You pressed the keyboard shortcut with your mesh selected and the armature being too far, the mesh becomes glitched.

Comment: after reading your reply, I went back to my project and check if this is the case. To make sure, I hit A to select all then hit ALT+A to unselect all then just click the camera. But still whenever I hit CTRL+ALT+0, same issue was encountered.